# Will android app crash if manifest use class not defined?

Tags: android, manifest, requirements

If we need to use a service say `tvinputservice` in `Manifest` but the service is available with `android.software.live_tv`. If a device doesn't have `android.software.live_tv` and we put `tvinputservice` in `Manifest`. Will the app crash on that device?

Comment: Easy answer, just try it yourself ;)

Comment: Why don't you just check if the package "android.software.live_tv" exist before trying to start the service?

Comment: @HendraWD This service is included in manifest. It's exported to the system. I'm wondering just put it in manifest, will it crash?

Comment: @AxelH I'm not able to find any androidtv device without that feature

Comment: But you can try with another feature on any device too see this. Not sure if you can emulate this choosing what feature can be present. But Anton Malyshev answer explain what will happen. Feature in the manifest are just use to filter apps on store.

Answer (score 0):

That will not allow to install the app on such devices (without the feature) through Google Play. That does not prevent you from installing the apk manually on such devices though, and the app will not crash until it actually try to use the functionality which is not present.

To allow installing the app on such devices via Google Play, you can use `android:required="false"` inside `uses-feature` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `Min SDk` and `Max SDK` in `Gradle` file in `Android Studio` 
and `Manifest` in Eclipse .
`Min SDK` and `Max SDK` is configure that your application run on which devices.